# We flip a coin twice. In the first round we get a TAIL. What's the probability that it will be a HEAD in the next throw?

Tags: probability

I Think the probability will be 1/2, because the second flip is not affected in any way be the first one. Contrary to that in my math book is said that the probability is 1/4. What am I missing here ?

Comment: Your book is wrong and you're right.

Comment: @Tryss is correct.

Comment: @AL.Ka: Please name and shame the book!

Comment: Maybe the book meant the probability of getting tail AND head (as first and second throw)?

Comment: @RobArthan , school books are worthless in my country

Comment: @AngeloRendina he maybe meant that in his head, but in the book is written exatly as i say above!

Answer (score 0):

The book is wrong and your intuition is right. Independently of intuition, let's see everything based on first principles:

This is a question about a conditional probability.

$$P(\text{second result: head}\ |\ \text{first result: tail})=$$
$$$$
$$=\frac{P(\text{first result: tail AND  second result: head})}{P(\text{first result: tail})}=$$
$$=\frac{\frac14}{\frac12}=\frac12.$$

(Assuming, of course, independence.)